# Application in Ember doesn't recognize the model so it ends up with index data being null

Tags: javascript, json, ember.js

I started an adventure with Ember a few weeks ago.
I have solid progress thanks to docs and example around the internet.

Sadly I hit a solid wall with this one as have almost copy-pasted models out of which most work and one and only one does not.

The error that I see in Inspector is:

```
Encountered a resource object with type "series", but no model was found for model name "series" (resolved model name using 'my-app@serializer:-json-api:.modelNameFromPayloadKey("series"))
Error while processing route: serie.index data is null...
```

I'm using mirage fixtures with success

```
// mirage/fixtures/files.js
export default [
{duration:'1',filename:'1.mkv',size:'1',id:'1',url:'dl/1.mkv'},
{duration:'2',filename:'2.mkv',size:'2',id:'2',url:'dl/2.mkv'}
];

// mirage/fixtures/series.js
export default [
{type:'show',title:'ser1',summary:'123',id:'11'},
{type:'show',title:'ser2',summary:'234',id:'12'}
];
```

Both use the same model for mirage

```
// mirage/model/file.js
// mirage/model/serie.js
import { Model } from 'ember-cli-mirage';
export default Model.extend({
});
```

I load fixtures this way:

```
// mirage/scenarios/default.js
export default function(server) {
server.loadFixtures();
}
```

And serializer is set on mirage this way:

```
// mirage/serializers/application.js
import { JSONAPISerializer } from 'ember-cli-mirage';
export default JSONAPISerializer.extend({
});
```

the only thing that I added to the config is

```
// added to mirage/config.js
this.namespace = 'api';
this.get('/series');
this.get('/series/:id');
this.get('/files');
this.get('/files/:id');
```

There is nothing more to do with mirage so let's move onto ember.

```
// app/adapters/application.js
application.js 
import DS from 'ember-data';
export default DS.JSONAPIAdapter.extend({
    namespace: 'api'
});
```

Both use the same component

```
// app/components/file-view.js
// app/components/serie-view.js
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Component.extend({
});
```

Models are defined this way:

```
// app/models/file.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    filename: DS.attr(),
    url: DS.attr(),
    art: DS.attr()
});

// app/models/serie.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr(),
    type: DS.attr(),
    summary: DS.attr()
});

// app/router.js
import Ember from 'ember';
import config from './config/environment';

const Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: config.locationType,
  rootURL: config.rootURL
});

Router.map(function() {
  this.route('serie', function() {
    this.route('show');
  });
  this.route('file', function() {
    this.route('show');
  });
});

export default Router;
```

Routes are almost identical

```
// app/routes/file.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
        model() {
                return this.get('store').findAll('file');
        }
});

// app/routes/serie.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model() {
        return this.get('store').findAll('serie');
    }
});
```

Same goes for the templates

```
// app/templates/file.hbs
<h2>Files</h2>

{{#each model as |fileUnit|}}
    {{file-view file=fileUnit}}
{{/each}}
{{outlet}}

// app/templates/serie.hbs
<h2>Series</h2>

{{#each model as |serieUnit|}}
    {{serie-view serie=serieUnit}}
{{/each}}
{{outlet}}
```

And last are the component templates:

```
// app/templates/components/file-view.js
<div>
<img src="cover.jpg" width=200 hight=200 alt="">
<h3>{{file.filename}} id: {{file.id}}</h3>
</div>

// app/templates/components/serie-view.js
<div>
<h3> {{serie.title}} id: {{serie.id}}</h3>
Summary: {{serie.summary}}
</div>
```

And as `http://localhost:4200/file` works fin the `http://localhost:4200/serie` throw an error

I tried to tackle this by removing the unnecessary code and models so that I could narrow down the problem but ended up having two models that are very similar with almost copy-pasted functionality yet only one working.

I really have no idea what is this about anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error gives you a hint

```
Encountered a resource object with type "series", but no model was found for model name "series" (resolved model name using 'my-app@serializer:-json-api:.modelNameFromPayloadKey("series"))
```

The problem is that ember [knows](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/Ember.Inflector.html) how to switch between `files` and `file` but not between `series` and `serie` because the word `series` is irregular ([both singular and plural](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/23268/is-series-plural-or-singular)) so `serie` is not its proper singular form.

Override [modelNameFromPayloadKey](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.JSONAPISerializer.html#method_modelNameFromPayloadKey) method in your serializer to return the proper model name for the key `'series'`:

```
export default DS.JSONAPISerializer.extend({
  modelNameFromPayloadKey(key) {
    // if payload model name is 'series', use 'serie'
    if (key === 'series') { 
      return 'serie';
    }
    // otherwise do the default thing
    return this._super(...arguments);
  }
});
```

Comment: making app/serializers/application.js and adding ```import DS from 'ember-data';
export default DS.JSONAPISerializer.extend({
 modelNameFromPayloadKey(key) {
 // if payload model name is 'series', use 'serie'
  if (key === 'series') { 
   return 'serie';
  }
  // otherwise do the default thing
  return this._super(...arguments);
 }
});``` helped.

Comment: Also just a second before you post proper solution I found out that renaming serie.js to series.js in models also helped as it try to force to bind to model of that name. strange thing... I was thinking it was something with the name but wasn't sure why and I was thinking it was 'type' attribute rather than name od model. Thanks once again